# Парсинг и изменение даты в кастомном формате

Tags: java, datetime, java-8, timestamp

Есть строка с датой и времнем в определенном формате

```
String date = "Tue Sep 11 08:28:59 EDT 2018";
```

На выходе хочу получить

```
11.09.2018 08:28
```

Но получаю

```
10.09.2018 15:28
```

Формат

```
"EEE MMM d HH:mm:ss z yyyy"
```

Хочу запарсить дату и вывести ее в другом формате

```
"dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm"
```

**Моя реализация:**

```
public static String getTime(String time, String inFormat, String outFormat) throws ParseException {
    Date date = new Date();
    SimpleDateFormat simpleFormet = new SimpleDateFormat(inFormat); 
    SimpleDateFormat simpleFormet2 = new SimpleDateFormat(outFormat); 
    date = simpleFormet.parse(time)
    return simpleFormet2.format(date);
}
```

Проблема в том что время всегда сбрасывается на текущее, подскажите как правильно сделать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Фокус в том, что ваше время `Tue Sep 11 08:28:59 EDT 2018` указано для часового пояса [`EDT`](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zones/edt), т.е. UTC-4, а объект `Date` хранит время по Гринвичу. Соответственно строка

```
simpleFormet2.format(date);
```

и дает время на 4 часа больше (а не текущее), чем было передано.

В Java8 появилась новая библиотека для работы со временем `java.time`. В ней есть класс `LocalDateTime` который хранит дату вместе с часовым поясом.

Использование:

```
public static String getTime2(String time, String inFormat, String outFormat) {
    DateTimeFormatter simpleFormet = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(inFormat); 
    DateTimeFormatter simpleFormet2 = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(outFormat); 
    LocalDateTime date = LocalDateTime.parse(time, simpleFormet);
    return date.format(simpleFormet2);
}
```

Comment: не совпадение типов в аргументах LocalDateTime.parse, simpleFormet не того типа что он ждет

Comment: Я [проверял](https://ideone.com/a2PMb4) Все совпадает. Скопируйте **весь** код как есть, а не отдельные строки

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы дата и время были такими же как изначально, нужно получить значение `z` в исходной строке. Это можно делать разными способами, в том числе используя [Joda DateTime](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/).

```
String timeZone = date.substring(20,3);
if ("EDT".equals(timeZone)) timeZone = "GMT-4";
simpleFormet2.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone(timeZone));
```